# How do I use upsert and $addToSet in conjunction?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to insert a document that looks like this:

```
{
    name: "app1",
    theArray: [...unique string elements...]
}
```

I tried to do an `upsert` using the query below but it somehow creates an array within an array if the document does not exist. If I use `$push` when the document does not exist, then the array is created fine. However I need to use `$addToSet` to maintain array element uniqueness.

Current query:

```
collection1.upsert({
            name: "app1",
        }, {
            $addToSet: {
                theArray: data // data is an array of ip addresses eg. ["1.1.1", "2.2.2.2"] which is not unique 
            }
        });
```

Executing the above query when there is no existing document in the db creates:

```
{
    name: "app-1",
    theArray: [
        //another array that contains the actual data.
    ]
}
```

Is there a way I can get this behavior with just a single query?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet
By definition of `addToSet` adds value to a list in your case your `data` itself is appended to a list which makes it a list of list

Comment: @BhavaniRavi - So I suppose I have to make sure the array exists prior to doing the addToSet. Which in turn means that I need two queries at least.

Comment: I got the answer. I need to use $each inside $addToSet.